# Set notBefore/notAfter for Dogtag Certificate Profile / XML Request

Tags: ssl-certificate, pki

I cannot figure this one out:

- Which ClassID do I have to use to add certificate validity inputs to the profile (is there an overview somewhere)?
- Once this is done: How do I add this in a request?

Here's a snippet of the Certificate Profile:

```
<Input id="i1">
    <ClassID>certReqInputImpl</ClassID>
    <Name>Certificate Request Input</Name>
    <Attribute name="cert_request_type">
....
<Input id="i2">
    <ClassID>???????</ClassID>
    <Name>Validity Constraint</Name>
    <Attribute name="notBefore">
        <Descriptor>
            <Syntax>string</Syntax>
            <Description>Not Before</Description>
        </Descriptor>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="notAfter">
        <Descriptor>
            <Syntax>string</Syntax>
            <Description>Not After</Description>
        </Descriptor>
    </Attribute>
</Input>
```

Thanks a lot in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this, as it seems that unfortunately there's no interest from the maintainers to continue supporting dogtag as a software itself - only as an underlying service for the IPA (freeipa.org).